# Create Stacked "Progress" Bar Chart in R with ggplot

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, dplyr, visualization

I am looking for a way to use ggplot to create a variation of a stacked bar chart. More of like a "progress bar" chart. I have Dates on the x axis, and a categorical variable "activity" on the y axis. Each activity has a "Red", "Yellow", or "Green" status. I want to plot the status of each activity over time. Problem is I don't have a numeric input to supply. And the dates are displaying weird and also not in chronological order. Hopefully you can get the idea of what I'm trying to do by looking at my plot and code below:

```
activity    date     status
a          11-10-21   red
a          11-17-21   red
a          11-24-21   yellow
a          12-01-21   green
b          11-10-21   red
b          11-17-21   yellow
b          11-24-21   green
b          12-01-21   green
c          11-10-21   yellow
c          11-17-21   green
c          11-24-21   green
c          12-01-21   green
```

Here is my code to generate the plot.

```
activity <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c")
date <- c("2021-11-10", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-24", "2021-12-01", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-17", 
"2021-11-24", "2021-12-01", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-17", "2021-11-24", "2021-12-01")
status <- c("red", "red", "yellow", "green", "red", "yellow", "green", "green", "yellow", 
"green", "green", "green")


df <- data.frame(activity, date, status)

df$activity <- as.factor(df$activity)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
df$status <- as.factor(df$status)

ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=activity, fill = status)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#6FC750", "#CC5939", "#D1CB28"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to switch to `geom_rect`.

As you have a categorial column to be mapped on `y` I transform it to a numeric which requires to put the labels back on the now continuous scale.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(date_end = date + lubridate::days(7))

width = .6

breaks <- seq(levels(factor(activity)))
labels <- levels(factor(activity))
ggplot(df, aes(fill = status)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = date, xmax = date_end, 
                ymin = as.numeric(factor(activity))  - width / 2, 
                ymax = as.numeric(factor(activity))  + width / 2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels= labels) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#6FC750", "#CC5939", "#D1CB28"))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

```r
set.seed(42)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(date_end = date + lubridate::days(sample(3:7, nrow(.), replace = TRUE)))

width = .6

breaks <- seq(levels(factor(activity)))
labels <- levels(factor(activity))
ggplot(df, aes(fill = status)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = date, xmax = date_end, 
                ymin = as.numeric(factor(activity))  - width / 2, 
                ymax = as.numeric(factor(activity))  + width / 2)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels= labels) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#6FC750", "#CC5939", "#D1CB28"))
```

[image]

Comment: great thanks, that worked. Is there a way I could outline each individual rectangle that makes up the full bar with a black outline?

Comment: Sure: `geom_rect(aes(...), color = "black")`

Comment: one more thing. Is there a way to fill in any gaps between the rectangles (for example if the dates were not all 1 week apart)?

Comment: Yep. What is needed is a start and end date, ie. instead of a fixed `date_end` you could fill this column with variable ending dates. See my edit where I used some random end dates.